# Crystal Reports override system format when published

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, crystal-reports-2010

An applied string format overrides every time the report is published to CMC. 
CStr(Year(Order_Date),0, "","") displays 2018 on Crystal client. However it comes up as 2,018 on BI Launch Pad. Seems some default format overriding the format.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your formula to CStr(Year(Order_Date), 0, "")
This means zero decimals and no thousand separator.